# PHP search suggestions

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I have a PHP script which works with jQuery to provide search suggestions. It pulls results from a MySQL database. However, I only want 5 results to display at once for the letter the user has typed but it seems all of the results appear. Why could this be?

My code is:

```
<p id="searchresults"><?php

$db=new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database');

if(isset($_POST['queryString'])){
$queryString=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
            if(strlen($queryString)>0){
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM search s WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%'");
                if($query){
                    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()){
                        echo '<a href="/search/'.$result->name.'/1/">';                     
                        $name=$result->name;            
                        echo ''.$name.'';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?></p>
```

I hope you can understand what I am trying to describe.

Comment: Is that `real_escape_string` really SQL-injection-safe?

Comment: @Uwe: `real_escape_string` provides SQL injection safety. So, yes. (Though PDO is better.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `"SELECT * FROM search s WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%'"`

to `"SELECT * FROM search s WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' LIMIT 5"`

if you want to limit it to 5 results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add pagination code to your page:

There is the sample code:

```
<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("your.hostaddress.com", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("address") or die(mysql_error()); 
 //This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it to page 1 
 if (!(isset($pagenum)))  
 { 
 $pagenum = 1; 
 } 
 //Here we count the number of results 
 //Edit $data to be your query 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topsites") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 
 //This is the number of results displayed per page 
 $page_rows = 4; 
 //This tells us the page number of our last page 
 $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 
 //this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages 
 if ($pagenum < 1) 
 { 
 $pagenum = 1;
 } 
 elseif ($pagenum > $last) 
 { 
 $pagenum = $last; 
 } 
 //This sets the range to display in our query 
 $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 
 //This is your query again, the same one... the only difference is we add $max into it 
 $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topsites $max") or die(mysql_error()); 
 //This is where you display your query results
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p )) 
 { 
 Print $info['Name']; 
 echo "<br>";
 }
 echo "<p>";
 // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
 echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";
 // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.
 if ($pagenum == 1) 
 {
 } 
 else 
 {
 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";
 echo " ";
 $previous = $pagenum-1;
 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";
 } 
 //just a space
 echo " -- ";
 //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links    
 if ($pagenum == $last)
 { 
 }
 else {
 $next = $pagenum+1;
 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";
 echo " ";
 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";
 }
 ?>
```

Source: [www.twitter.com/ZishanAdThandar](http://www.twitter.com/ZishanAdThandar)